# Changing Target Object in AOP After advice

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I am changing target object in AOP @After advice

My Target object is Trade and my methods are setPrice(...) and getPrice(..), getVolume() etc

1)Situation 1 : In the After Advice of getPrice() , if I modify the price and set to Trade object and access at client side - I don't get modified value

2)Situation 2 : In the After Advice of getVolume() , if I modify the price and set to Trade object and access at client side - I GET modified value

Could you please explain the behaviour?

Comment: No I can't. I'm sorry but my crystal ball is currently out of use. Seriously how can we guess what happen in *your* code if you show nothing. Without any code (or better a [mcve]) this question is off topic for SO rules and will be closed...

Comment: @SergeBallesta ..ok sir..i m sorry...I will prepare a test code and add..As of now I have project code which I can not add, I will add test code soon..thank you

Answer (score 1):

I am able to resolve it. When I tried creating test code, it turned out something different.

In my Aspect , when I use

```
     @Before(value="execution( * *.getPrice(..))") and
     @After(value="execution( * *.getPrice(..))")


    public class MyAspect {


    @Before(value="execution( * *.getPrice(..))")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinpoint){
        System.out.println("In Before Advice : And the target method is : "                         +joinpoint.getSignature().getName() );

        Object obj = joinpoint.getTarget();


        TradeDaoImpl dao = (TradeDaoImpl)obj;
        System.out.println("In Before Advice : Current DAO price is  : " +dao);
        dao.setPrice(100);
        System.out.println("In Before Advice : New price is " + dao);

    }



    @After(value="execution( * *.getPrice(..))")
    public void logAfter(JoinPoint joinpoint){
        System.out.println("In After Advice : And the target method is : "                         +joinpoint.getSignature().getName() );

        Object obj = joinpoint.getTarget();

        TradeDaoImpl dao = (TradeDaoImpl)obj;
        System.out.println("In After Advice : Current DAO price is  : " +dao);
        dao.setPrice(200);
        System.out.println("In After Advice : New price is " + dao);

    }

}
```

The output is what I expected

```
    In Before Advice : And the target method is : getPrice
    In Before Advice : Current DAO price is  : TradeDAOImpl - toString , price is 0
    In Before Advice : New price is TradeDAOImpl - toString , price is 100
    In After Advice : And the target method is : getPrice
    In After Advice : Current DAO price is  : TradeDAOImpl - toString , price is 100
    In After Advice : New price is TradeDAOImpl - toString , price is 200
    **********************************In Junit
    In junit : retuned price is 100
    In Junit Test case  : TradeDAOImpl - toString , price is 200
```

Retuned price is 100 as After Advice works after value is returned

But if i do toString on TradeDAOImpl , i can see that now the current value of price in TradeDAOImpl is 200

But if I use

```
    @Before(value="execution( * com.dimple.dao.TradeDaoImpl.*(..))") and
    @After(value="execution( * com.dimple.dao.TradeDaoImpl.*(..))")

    In Before Advice : And the target method is : getPrice
    In Before Advice : Current DAO price is  : TradeDAOImpl - toString , price is 0
    In Before Advice : New price is TradeDAOImpl - toString , price is 100
    In After Advice : And the target method is : getPrice
    In After Advice : Current DAO price is  : TradeDAOImpl - toString , price is 100
    In After Advice : New price is TradeDAOImpl - toString , price is 200
     **********************************In Junit
    In junit : retuned price is 100
    In Before Advice : And the target method is : toString
    In Before Advice : Current DAO price is  : TradeDAOImpl - toString , price is 200
    In Before Advice : New price is TradeDAOImpl - toString , price is 100
    In After Advice : And the target method is : toString
    In After Advice : Current DAO price is  : TradeDAOImpl - toString , price is 100
    In After Advice : New price is TradeDAOImpl - toString , price is 200
    In Junit Test case  : TradeDAOImpl - toString , price is 100
```

I have understood that my toString() is further calling before and after advice
Because of that , I am getting return value as 100

Although I have set the price as 200 in after advice , if i try to get that in some way , i wont be able to do that as my pointcut expression is too broad

Sorry for inconvenience caused due to question without test code.
Thanks @SergeBallesta for your helpful comment.